# How to interpret the second raw moment?

Tags: variance, interpretation, moments, variability

I know the second raw moment is defined as $E(X^2)$, for $X$ being a random variable drawn from any distribution or a given large data sample. I also know that based on variance decomposition,
variance ($X$), the second central moment

Variance ($X$) = $E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$
Here comes my question, how to interpret the second raw moment (from the origin). Is it a measure for variability as well? Can I say that it measures the variability of the data sample centered on the origin?

Comment: Except in the case of a centered variable for which $E(X^2) = \operatorname{Var}(X)$ since $E(X) =0$, it can't generally be used as a variability measure. Take for example the case of a constant variable $X=c$ then $E(X^2) = c^2$ which can be made as large as you want while $\operatorname{Var}(X) = 0$ for any value of $c$.

Comment: Thanks that is very intuitive, since being constant can never be variable. Maybe I can interpret it as the average dispersion from the origin (which resembles the measure of standard deviation).

Comment: @Hujinii the standard deviation is a measure of dispersion from the mean not from the origin

Comment: I know what is a standard deviation. Here I meant the interpretation of the second raw moment. If we give it a square root, maybe it can reflect the average dispersion from the origin?

Comment: You might say "*average squared distance from the origin*".

Comment: thanks for you answer

Answer (score 1):

'variability of the data sample centred on the origin' or dispersion from the origin is perhaps not a useful concept. The notion of variability in statistics is usually the same for $X$ as it is for $X + a$. E.g. $Var(X) = Var(X + a)$ and $IQR(X) = IQR(X+a)$.

Further, as @periwinkle mentioned, if $X = c = \text{constant}$ there is no variability thus the notion of variability from the origin maybe doesn't make sense.

I think all we can really conclude is that, $E(X^2)$ is just the mean value of $X^2$. Or alternatively, if we must phrase $E(X^2)$ in terms of the origin, $E(X^2)$  will measure the mean *distance* from the origin that $X$ is.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. In that sense, would $E(X^2)$ a better measure for the mean distance from the origin.

Comment: @Hujinii Yes, $E(X^2)$ is just the mean distance of $X^2$ from the origin

Comment: $E(X^2)$ is the mean *squared* distance to the origin.

Comment: thanks for your answer